# Show rat inmaze final path cordinates using Stack with C++ language

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I have done my assignment. And I am printing coordinates also(from source to a destination where rat visited/get deadends) but I just want to print the final rat path from source to destination(excluding visited and deadend). I am creating a function "void print(node p)" (where the node is the class name and p is the object but when I call it after while loop it doesn't show anything. And when I call in each line it shows all coordinates (visited/deadends). Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?. What should I do to print the final elements from the stack?

**class**

```
class node {
public:
    int x, y;
    int pos;
    
    node(int i, int j)
    {
        x = i;
        y = j;
        
        // Initially Position 
        // set to 0 
        pos = 0;
    }
    /*void setValue(int i, int j)
    {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }*/
    
    int getrow()
    {
        return x;
    }
    int getcol()
    {
        return y;
    }
};
```

**print cordinates functions**

```
void print(node p)
{
    cout << "(" << p.getrow() << "," << p.getcol() << ")" << "\t";
}
```

**function that checks deadends and open path and backtrack**

```
bool isReachable(int maze[SIZE][SIZE] , int& count)
{
    bool visited[SIZE][SIZE];
    
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"\n" <<"Start at cordinate" << "("<<i<< "," << j << ")"<<endl;
    cout << endl;
        
    stack<node> s;
    node path1(i,j);
    node temp(i, j);
    s.push(temp);
    
    while (!s.empty()) {
        // Pop the top node and move to  
        // left, right, top, down or  
        // backtrack according the value of node's 
        // pos variable. 
        
        temp = s.top();
        
        int d = temp.pos;
        i = temp.x, j = temp.y;
        
        // Increment the direction and 
        // push the node in the stack again. 
        temp.pos++;
        s.pop();
        s.push(temp);
                
        // If we reach the coordinates 
        // return true 
        if (i == SIZE-1 and j == SIZE-1) {
            count++;
            cout << endl;   
            cout << "\n"<<"Exit at coordinate" <<"(" <<i <<","<<j <<")"<< endl;
            maze[i][j]=3;
            return true;
        }
        
        // Checking the Up direction. 
        if (d == 0)
        {
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && maze[i - 1][j] == 0 && visited[i - 1][j])
            {
                node temp1(i - 1, j);
                visited[i - 1][j] = false;
                s.push(temp1);
                count++;
                maze[i][j] = 3;
                path1 = s.top();    
                print(path1);
            }
            
        }
        
        // Checking the left direction 
        else if (d == 1)
        {
            if (j - 1 >= 0 && maze[i][j - 1] == 0 && visited[i][j - 1])
            {
                node temp1(i, j - 1);
                visited[i][j - 1] = false;
                s.push(temp1);
                count++; 
                maze[i][j] = 3;
                path1 = s.top();
                print(path1);
            }
        }
        
        // Checking the down direction 
        else if (d == 2)
        {
            if (i + 1 < SIZE && maze[i + 1][j] == 0 && visited[i + 1][j])
            {
                node temp1(i + 1, j);
                visited[i + 1][j] = false;
                s.push(temp1);
                count++;
                maze[i][j] = 3;
                path1 = s.top();
                print(path1);
        
            }
        }
        // Checking the right direction 
        else if (d == 3)
        {
            if (j + 1 < SIZE && maze[i][j + 1] == 0 && visited[i][j + 1])
            {
                node temp1(i, j + 1);
                visited[i][j + 1] = false;
                s.push(temp1);
                count++;
                maze[i][j] = 3;
                path1 = s.top();
                print(path1);
            }
        }
        
        // If none of the direction leads to end point 
        // pop the value  from where it enter.
        else
        {
            visited[temp.x][temp.y] = true;
            s.pop();
            count--;
            maze[i][j] = -1;
        
            path1 = s.top();
            print(path1);
        }
    }
    
    return count;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Main function**

```
int main()
{
    // Initially setting the visited 
    // array to true (unvisited) 
    
    bool visited[SIZE][SIZE];
    
    memset(visited, true, sizeof(visited));
    
    int maze[SIZE][SIZE] =
        {//0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        {  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },//0
        { -1,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 },//1
        {  0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0 },//2
        {  0,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0 },//3
        {  0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1,-1,-1, 0 },//4
        {  0,-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },//5
        {  0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1, 0 },//6
        {  0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0 },//7
        {  0,-1, 0,-1,-1, 0,-1, 0,-1,-1 },//8
        {  0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0 } //9
    
        };
    
    int count = 0;
    
    cout <<'\n'<<"Original maze!" << '\n';
    cout << endl;
    printMaze(maze);
    if (isReachable(maze, count)) {
        cout << '\n' << "Final Path Maze"<<endl;
        cout << "Path length:" << count<<endl;
        cout << endl;
    
    }
    else
        cout << "No Exit Found!" << '\n';
    
        printMaze(maze);
        
        getchar();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging you program?

Comment: Yes, I am trying but I don't know what I am logically doing wrong. I am calling a print function in each portion. However, the print function only calls once after while loop but when I did so it does not show any coordinates

Comment: Your `visited` in `isReachable` is not initialized.